# Remove alternating spaces from a string

Tags: c#, string, replace

How do I remove spaces from a string, but only if they are adjacent to a non-space?

E.g. I would like to turn `P u m p k i n   p i e` into `Pumpkin pie`.

My current solution, of `String.Join("", input.Split(' '));` wouldn't have preserved the space in the above example.

Comment: Why is this a bad question?

Comment: It's basically a "write my code for me" question.

Comment: @mason after I've attempted it myself, which stackexchange supports

Comment: FYI, your attempt `String.Join("", input.Split(' '))` is equivalent to `String.Replace(" ", "")` but probably less efficient (though still wrong)

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to match spaces followed by a non-space or 2+ spaces, and replace them with an empty string:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...
var str = "P u m p k i n   p i e";
var res = Regex.Replace(str, @"\s(?=\S|\s{2,})", "");
```

[Demo of the regex.](https://regex101.com/r/rtkbO1/1)

[Demo of the program.](http://ideone.com/L6ZQtt)

Comment: Where is the `Regex` class from?

Comment: `System.Regex`?

Comment: @minseong `System.Text.RegularExpressions`. I know, the `Text` part is odd.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not proud of it, but if you don't like regex.

```
string[] splitters = new string[] { "  " };
string input = "P u m p k i n   p i e";
string output = String.Join(" ", input.Split(splitters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => x.Replace(" ", String.Empty)));
```

Comment: What's the reason for not being proud of this?

Comment: It works, people typically use regex to manipulate strings though.

Comment: @FrumRoll This only works if there are exactly three consecutive space characters.

Comment: @MatiasCicero it seems to be working for me so far

Comment: @minseong Be warned then. if there are more consecutive spaces on the string, then the split won't work.

Comment: @MatiasCicero Fixed to remove consecutive spaces >= 2.

Comment: @FrumRoll Now that's more like it

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
string text = "I    l o v e   P u m p k i n                p i e";

// Use a special character for word delimiter. In this specific case, #
string result = Regex.Replace(text, @"\s{2,}", "#");

// Get the words
IEnumerable<string> words = result.Split('#').Select(w => String.Join(String.Empty, w.Split(' ')));

// Join the words with space character
result = String.Join(" ", words);
```

Final result is `"I love pumpkin pie"`

---

If you like one-liners:

```
string result = String.Join(" ",
        Regex.Replace(text, @"\s{2,}", "#")
        .Split('#')
        .Select(w =>
            String.Join(String.Empty, w.Split(' '))));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "P u m p k i n   p i e";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "(?<! ) (?! )", "");
output = Regex.Replace(output, " {2,}", " ");
```